# FITS_rec and selection of data: masking instead of "true" filtering?

Tags: select, masking, astropy, fits, recarray

Probably a duplicate to [Ashley's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40785250/astropy-fits-how-to-write-out-a-table-with-rows-sliced-out/40787127#40787127) (but I can't comment -yet ;) ).

I have the same issue when trying to add a column to a sub-selection/sample of my initial *FITS_rec* (based on *numpy*'s *recarray*); all the rows reappear (AND the filling of this new column doesn't seem to be respected...). "*hdu_sliced._get_raw_data()*" proposed by Vlas Sokolov is a solution that is working very fine for me, but I was wondering:

1) What are "the better ways" suggested by Iguananaut? I certainly need someone to just google it for me; the newbie me is feeling stuck :$ (Staying in a *FITS_rec* would be required).

2) Is that an expected behaviour? Meaning, are we really wanting to work on a "masked array" which would a copy of our original array? What is worrying me the most is the "collapse" of the values in the new computed column. See below:

```
# A nice FITS_rec
a1 = np.array(['NGC1001', 'NGC1002', 'NGC1003'])
a2 = np.array([11.1, 12.3, 15.2])
col1 = fits.Column(name='target', format='20A', array=a1)
col2 = fits.Column(name='V_mag', format='E', array=a2)

cols = fits.ColDefs([col1, col2])
hdu = fits.BinTableHDU.from_columns(cols)

ori_rec=hdu.data

ori_rec
`
```

> FITS_rec([('NGC1001', 11.1), ('NGC1002', 12.3), ('NGC1003', 15.2)],
>            dtype=(numpy.record, [('target', 'S20'), ('V_mag', '

```
# Sub-selection
bug=ori_rec[ori_rec["V_mag"]>12.]
bug
```

> FITS_rec([('NGC1002', 12.3), ('NGC1003', 15.2)],
>            dtype=(numpy.record, [('target', 'S20'), ('V_mag', '

So far so good...

```
# Let's add a new column
col0=bug.columns
col1 =fits.ColDefs([fits.Column(name='new',format='D',array=bug.field("V_mag")+1.)])
newbug = fits.BinTableHDU.from_columns(col0 + col1).data
```

> FITS_rec([('NGC1001', 11.1, 13.30000019), ('NGC1002', 12.3, 16.20000076),
>             ('NGC1003', 15.2,  0.        )],
>            dtype=(numpy.record, [('target', 'S20'), ('V_mag', '

...AND ... the values of the new column for  NGC1002 and NGC1003 are correct but in the row of NGC1001 and NGC1002 respectively... :|

Any enlightenment will be welcomed :)

Comment: Thanks for the nice, detailed post.  I'll have an answer in a few...

Answer (score 0):

This is a confusing problem, and it stems from the fact that there are many layers of legacy classes and data structures in `astropy.io.fits` (stemming back from earlier versions of PyFITS).  For example, you can see in your example that `hdu.data` is a `FITS_rec` object, which is like a Numpy recarray (itself a soft-deprecated legacy class), but it also has a `.columns` attribute (as you've noted):

```
>>> bug.columns
ColDefs(
    name = 'target'; format = '20A'
    name = 'V_mag'; format = 'E'
)
```

This in turn actually holds references back to the original arrays from which you described the columns.  For example:

```
>>> bug.columns['target'].array
chararray(['NGC1001', 'NGC1002', 'NGC1003'],
      dtype='|S20')
```

You can see here that even though `bug` is a "slice" of your original table, the arrays referenced through `bug.columns` are still contain the original, unsliced array data.  So when you do something like in your original post

```
>>> col0 = bug.columns
>>> col1 = fits.ColDefs([fits.Column(name='new',format='D',array=bug.field("V_mag")+1.)])
```

it's doing its best here to figure out the intent, but `col0` here has no idea that `bug` is a slice of the original table anymore, it only has the original "coldefs" with the full columns to rely on here.

Most of these classes, including `FITS_rec`, `Column`, and especially `ColDefs` almost *never* need to be used directly anymore.  Unfortunately not all of the documentation has been updated to reflect this fact, and there are a lot of older tutorials and example code that show usage of these classes.  Nobody with the requisite expertise has been able to take the time to update the docs and clarify this point.

On occasion `Column` is useful if you already have columnar data with each column in a separate array, and you want to build a table from it and give some specific FITS attributes to the table columns.  But I have redesigned much of the API so that you can take native Python data structures like Numpy arrays and save them to FITS files without *worrying* about the details of how FITS is implemented or annoying things like FITS data format codes in many cases.

This work is slightly incomplete, because it seems if you want to define a FITS table from some columnar arrays, you still need to use the `Column` class and specify a FITS format at a minimum (but you never need to use `ColDefs` directly):

```
>>> hdu = fits.BinTableHDU.from_columns([fits.Column(name='target', format='20A', array=a1), fits.Column(name='V_mag', format='E', array=a2)])
>>> hdu.data
FITS_rec([('NGC1001', 11.1), ('NGC1002', 12.3), ('NGC1003', 15.2)],
      dtype=(numpy.record, [('target', 'S20'), ('V_mag', '<f4')]))
```

However, you can also work with Numpy structured arrays directly, and I usually find that simpler personally, as it allows you to ignore most FITS-isms and just focus on your data, for those cases where it's not important to finely tweak the FITS-specific stuff.  For example, to define a structured array for your data, there are several ways to go about that, but you might try:

```
>>> nrows = 3
>>> data = np.empty(nrows, dtype=[('target', 'S20'), ('V_mag', np.float32)])
>>> data['target'] = a1
>>> data['V_mag'] = a2
>>> data
array([('NGC1001', 11.100000381469727), ('NGC1002', 12.300000190734863),
       ('NGC1003', 15.199999809265137)],
      dtype=[('target', 'S20'), ('V_mag', '<f4')])
```

and then you can instantiate a `BinTableHDU` directly from this array:

```
>>> hdu = fits.BinTableHDU(data)
>>> hdu.data
FITS_rec([('NGC1001', 11.1), ('NGC1002', 12.3), ('NGC1003', 15.2)],
      dtype=(numpy.record, [('target', 'S20'), ('V_mag', '<f4')]))
>>> hdu.header
XTENSION= 'BINTABLE'           / binary table extension
BITPIX  =                    8 / array data type
NAXIS   =                    2 / number of array dimensions
NAXIS1  =                   24 / length of dimension 1
NAXIS2  =                    3 / length of dimension 2
PCOUNT  =                    0 / number of group parameters
GCOUNT  =                    1 / number of groups
TFIELDS =                    2 / number of table fields
TTYPE1  = 'target  '
TFORM1  = '20A     '
TTYPE2  = 'V_mag   '
TFORM2  = 'E       '
```

Likewise when it comes to things like masking and slicing and adding new columns, working directly with the native Numpy data structures is best.

Or, as suggested in the answers to [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40785250/astropy-fits-how-to-write-out-a-table-with-rows-sliced-out/40787127#40787127), use the Astropy [`Table`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/) API and don't mess with low-level FITS stuff at all if you can help it.  Because as I discussed, it contains several layers of legacy interfaces that make things confusing (and that long term should probably be cleaned up, but it's hard to do because code that uses them in some way or another are *pervasive*).  The Table API was designed from the ground-up to make table manupulations, including things like masking rows and adding columns, relatively easy.  Whereas the old PyFITS APIs never quite worked for many simple cases.

I hope this answer was edifying--I know it's maybe a bit long and confusing.  If there is anything specific I can clear up let me know.